# Calling a function without taking allocation of object in c++

Tags: visual-c++, object, dev-c++

Is it possible to call a function using reference operator(->) without allocation of memory.
I tried this code in some case

```
Foo *fooObject;
fooObject->someFunction;
```

I have confusion about this matter. This run fine in Dev C++ but crash in visual c++.

Comment: This is not valid code (undefined behavior actually). It makes no sense, since fooObject (pointer to Foo) is not initialized. It can points to anywhere. If you don't want to allocate memory on heap, you can do it for example on stack: Foo fooObj; fooObj.someFunction().

Comment: What do you mean with "possible"? You can write it (your program is "well-formed" in the sense that it can be compiled), but as maverik says it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's never possible to use -> without allocation of memory because this operator is trying to dereference a pointer to an object... therefore the object must exist.

The object pointed to must exist... this is the "allocation of memory" and this can be done on the stack or heap.

The following syntax...

```
fooObject->func();
```

is equivalent to

```
(*fooObject).func()
```

so to be able to do `*fooObject`, the object pointed to by `fooObject` must exist.

In your code

```
Foo *fooObject;
```

Is a **dangling pointer** because you have not pointed it at an object. The pointer value may be NULL or point to some completely random block of memory: to deference it will cause you problems as there is no guarantee what you're deferencing ... this is called **"undefined behavior"**.

To allocate memory for your object you can do it on the stack like this

```
Foo fooObject;
```

You could then, if you liked, use a pointer to the object...

```
Foo *fooObjectPTR = &fooObject;
```

But note, that the object allocated on the stack will only exist whilst it is in-scope. When it goes out of scope, it is destroyed, and your pointer will become a dangling pointer again so must not be used.

Or you can allocate on the heap like this

```
Foo *fooObjectPTR = new Foo();
```

If you allocate on the heap, you must be careful to free the allocated memory later using `delete`

Comment: I think it would be better to say that you can not use -> unless your pointer is pointing at a valid object. You can assign your pointer to a stack based variable. Foo *fooPTR; Foo foo_stk_obj; fooPTR = &foo_stk_obj;

Comment: @Freddy... yep get your meaning... by "allocation of memory" I had meant heap or stack, but you're right it could be clearer... updating answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call static functions on a class without having an instance actually exist, however this is done by using the `::` notation, and then the function is run outside of the scope any specific instance - static member functions of a class have no implicit `this` pointer:

```
class Foo {
public:
  static void someFunction(void) {std::cout << "BOO!\n";};
};

...
int main(...) {
  Foo::someFunction();
  return 0;
}
```

The standards state in [class-static]: "A static member may
be referred to using the class member access syntax, *in which case the object-expression
is always evaluated*."

Contrary to this, [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyh8hetw.aspx) states: `The left side of a member-selection operator (. or –>) that selects a static member function is not evaluated`, which implies that the following is valid for VC++, but not in standards-compliant C++:

```
Foo* not_allocated;
not_allocated->someFunction();
```

Comment: What the Standard says about this: "A postfix expression followed by a dot `.` or an arrow `->` [...] and then followed by an id-expression, is a postfix expression. The postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated;" with a footnote "If the class member access expression is evaluated, the subexpression evaluation happens even if the result is unnecessary to determine the value of the entire postfix expression, **for example if the id-expression denotes a static member**." [expr.ref]/1

Comment: Perhaps more important (?) is [class.static], which states "A static member may be referred to using the class member access syntax, in which case the object-expression is always evaluated". I'll update my answer.